# Getting out parameters from stored proedure

Tags: javascript, stored-procedures, mariadb

I'm using node and calling a stored procedure in MariaDB.  The stored procedure has 3 out parameters.  If I call perform the following query in HeidiSQL it works without problem:

```
    CALL weekFromDate('syberdyne', '2016/01/23', @dtSOW, @siWeek, @siYear);
    SELECT @dtSOW, @siWeek, @siYear;
```

However if I execute the exact same query in node/javascript I get an error:

```
    MySQL, Error: ER_PARSE_ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT @dtSOW, @siWeek, @siYear' at line 1
```

What is the correct way to access 'out' parameters in node/Javascript?

Answer (score 0):

Solved, by modifying the connection routine in node.js and adding the parameter:

```
    multipleStatements:true
```